# Python Message Cipher Indexation Error + WhiteSpace issue

Tags: python, indexing

I am working on an exercise to encode a message in Python. The following function is supposed to take in a message and a number to shift the letters in each word by that amount in the alphabet i.e. the letter a if moved 3 spaced would become d.

I have two issues:

1. The length of the alphabet is only 26 characters long. If you shift a letter too far right i.e. past the 26th position of Z you get the following error:

IndexError: string index out of range

I'd be happy with a fix that shifts the index back to the start again and moves the letter index based on the remainder of whatever goes past 26 characters i.e. if there is a shift of 9 with the char y then the remaining 9 after 26 could be positioned start from a again, making y the letter i.

2. If I were to input a message with spaces i.e. "I need help", the returned characters do not retain the original white space between each word.

Can anyone help with questions 1 or 2?

```
def message_to_code():
normal_message = input(str("Please enter a message you would like coded: "))
Cipher_shift = int(input("Please enter the whole number you would like to act as the key to hide your message "))
Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Cipher_message = ' '
for letter in normal_message:
    Encrypted_letter = Alphabet.find(letter) + Cipher_shift
    Cipher_message = Cipher_message + Alphabet[Encrypted_letter] 
return print(Cipher_message)
```

message_to_code()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem can be easily fixed by checking if `Alphabet.find(letter) + Cipher_shift >= len(Alphabet)`. If it is, than `Encrypted_letter = Encrypted_letter - len(Alphabet)`.

Your second problem was tricky to completely understand, but I think the fix you are looking for is checking if `letter` is a space. If it is, loop to the next character, if it's not, do the logic with that character.

The bug fixes look like this:

```
def message_to_code():
normal_message = input(str("Please enter a message you would like coded: "))
Cipher_shift = int(input("Please enter the whole number you would like to act as the key to hide your message "))
Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Cipher_message = ' '
for letter in normal_message:
    if letter != ' ':
        Encrypted_letter = Alphabet.find(letter) + Cipher_shift

        if Encrypted_letter >= len(Alphabet):
            Encrypted_letter -= len(Alphabet)

        Cipher_message = Cipher_message + Alphabet[Encrypted_letter]
    else:
        Cipher_message += ' '
```

I also fixed some other problems. For example, if you have a capital letter, your original code wouldn't catch that, since `Alphabet` is only filled with lower-case letters. To fix this, I added a second array dedicated to capital-letters, and check to see if `letter` is capital or not.

The second fix is checking if `letter` is a part of the alphabet or not. If it isn't, that would mean `letter` is: '/', '.', ',', ':', ';', etc. If it does happen to be one of these characters, it just adds its original self to the encrypted string.

The modified code looks like this:

```
def message_to_code():
normal_message = input(str("Please enter a message you would like coded: "))
Cipher_shift = int(input("Please enter the whole number you would like to act as the key to hide your message "))
Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
AlphabetCaps = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Cipher_message = ""

is_letter = True
for letter in normal_message:
    if letter != ' ':
        if Alphabet.find(letter) != -1:
            Encrypted_letter = Alphabet.find(letter) + Cipher_shift
            is_letter = True
        elif AlphabetCaps.find(letter) != -1:
            Encrypted_letter = AlphabetCaps.find(letter) + Cipher_shift
            is_letter = True
        else:
            is_letter = False
        
        if is_letter:
            if Encrypted_letter >= len(Alphabet):
                Encrypted_letter -= len(Alphabet)

            if Alphabet.find(letter) != -1:
                Cipher_message += Alphabet[Encrypted_letter]
            else:
                Cipher_message += AlphabetCaps[Encrypted_letter]
        else:
            Cipher_message += letter
    else:
        Cipher_message += ' '

return print(Cipher_message)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works in my text editor.  I'm new to this so will work through your logic.